# Rails Previous Sunday in Relation to Any DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

Working with a Rails 3 application. Given a DateTime, I need to produce the Datetime for the previous Sunday. If the DateTime is a Sunday, then I want that Sunday itself back. Here's some examples:

```
November 7, 2011 => November 6, 2011
November 6, 2011 => November 6, 2011
November 5, 2011 => October 30, 2011
```

Any ideas? I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
class DateTime
  def previous_sunday
    self - wday
  end
end
```

…but this is so easy, there's no reason to monkey patch it into the class :)

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date'; now = DateTime.now
#=> #<DateTime: 2011-11-10T21:10:04-07:00 (…)>
irb(main):002:0> sunday = now - now.wday
#=> #<DateTime: 2011-11-06T21:10:04-07:00 (…)>
```

The `wday` (weekday) will be `0` for any Sunday, and so no change to the date will take place.

Comment: Instead of DateTime.now, I'd use Date.today.

Comment: @Sprachprofi Yes, but the OP asked for a `DateTime`, not a `Date`.

Comment: should have been `sunday = now - now.wday.days` I believe?

Answer (score 49):

Rails has a convenience method for calculating the beginning of the week.

```
irb(main):001:0> Date.today.beginning_of_week(:sunday)
#=> Sun, 16 Dec 2012
```

See the `Date` Rails extensions for other possibilities: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Date.html

**Update**: Rails 5.2 adds convenience methods to find the next/previous occurrence of a day.

```
[1] pry(main)> Date.today.prev_occurring(:sunday)
#=> Sun, 29 Apr 2018
```

See the `DateAndTime::Calculations` documentation for [`prev_occurring`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-prev_occurring) and [`next_occurring`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_occurring).